# error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "008000 " in remote config in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, numberformatexception, firebase-remote-config

i have been implementing remote config using firebase referring this --> https://www.warmodroid.xyz/tutorial/firebase/how-to-set-firebase-remote-config-values-in-android/

i took one textview in layout to test but it crashing with `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "008000 "`

here is my code:---

```
   {
    val configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
       // .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600L)
        .build()
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig?.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)

    getRemoteConfigValues()
    }
   .
   .
    .
    .
 private fun getRemoteConfigValues() {
    //here I have set the cache expiration duration to 1 hour
    //It means app will refresh after every 1 hour to check
    // if some changes are there in remote config
    var cacheExpiration: Long = 3600

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fetch Succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fetch Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        //changing the textview and backgorund color
        setRemoteConfigValues()
    }
}

private fun setRemoteConfigValues() {
    val remoteValueBackground = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(COLOR_CONFIG_KEY)
    if (remoteValueBackground.isNotEmpty()) {
        huuuuuu?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(remoteValueBackground))
    }
}
```

i debug this line `huuuuuu?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(remoteValueBackground))` for value it shows `remoteValueBackground="#0080000\t"` in debugger though im passing a proper value from remote config firebase console

test case:--

1. if i pass hardcoded value in `huuuuuu?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(#008000))` --> it worked
2. if i pass remoteValueBackground.trim() method it worked

but why this `huuuuuu?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(remoteValueBackground))` is giving  `"#008000\t"`

[image]

thanks need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message says there's a space in the string, see?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "008000 "
                                                          ^
```

so it can't be parsed as an integer.

*edit* it's actually a tab character according to this:

```
"#008000\t"
```

that's why `.trim()` works, it removes the whitespace either way. Is that character present in the Firebase text field? Maybe try typing it in again (especially if you pasted it in)

Comment: need help of yours here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424508/push-notification-enable-and-disable-by-using-switch

Comment: I don't know anything about Firebase messaging, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

just call trim() method to remove whitespaces

```
huuuuuu?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(remoteValueBackground.trim()))
```